# .writeValue will not let me write hex string to characteristic to enable notifications

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

My ble peripheral requires me to write the hex value 0x0001 to my CCCD descriptor to enable notifications. When I try to write the value to the characteristic with the .notify property, I get the following error:

```
Cannot invoke 'writeValue' with an argument list of type '(Data:String, for: CBCharacteristic)'
```

How can I write the value to my characteristic so I receiving notifications?

I've tried to remove the .writeValue line and just keep the .setNotifyValue line, but when I send data from my device, I am not notified. Do I have to read the value when I am notified? Should the notification just write the value to my output?

```
  if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
    print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .notify")
    NUB5.writeValue(Data: "0x0001", for: characteristic)
    NUB5.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
  }
```

//     The BL652 requires the value of 0x0001 to be written to the TX CCCD to notify us of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off Fayer 's response, I had to encode the data. The following code worked for me before .writeValue:

```
var TxNotify:UInut=0001
let enableBytes = NSData(bytes: &TxNotify, length:8)
NUB5.writeValue(enableBytes as Data, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
NUB5.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)` should be enough. 
   Did you implement `peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:)` method? Could you show the code?
2. `writeValue` takes `Data` input but you try to pass `String`. You need to encode it e.g.:

```
let encodedString = "Lorem ipsum".data(using: .utf8)

let number = 1
let encodedNumber = withUnsafeBytes(of: number) { Data($0) }
```